# How to append a text to applet textbox from webdriver?

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, japplet

I have applet textbox on my webpage , which selenium webdriver does not recognize. I need to append a default text inside that textbox when applets is loaded. 
How can I accomplish this?

Applet class is coded within Javascript and the HTML structure is below.

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="hidden" value="FFM" name="origintype"/>
<applet height="180" width="420" name="frtext" codebase="/applets"     code="textarea_counter_applet.class"/>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium doesn't natively support applets, you have to find outside tools to extend selenium for applet use. Try http://docs.codehaus.org/display/FEST/Selenium